# Scalable and extensible cross-platform architecture for a mostly solo development pipeline?

Tags: architecture, continuous-integration, devops, system-administration

I'm looking for a solid foundation for a development infrastructure that utilizes CI/CD tools in accordance to today's best practices (dated end-of-year 2016). I want to have a setup for a solo development environment, but would appreciate tips on extending it for higher throughput and higher availability eventually; **if I were to start a company, what is the best foundation to do this at this moment in time to allow for dynamic growth?**

I understand that this is a broad question, and there are different ways to do this for different work flows across different stacks. I want to keep things fully open sourced and virtualized, though I don't mind answers that aren't as well. As long as it's fairly modular in terms of tooling, where I could kill a server and redeploy a different one with relative ease (e.g. if I wanted to switch from Puppet to Chef, I'd just kill the Puppet server and provision a Chef one).

Some tools that I'm familiar with (that I'm currently studying) that fulfills a role in the devOps architecture:

- Configuration Management: Puppet, Ansible
- CI: Jenkins, Travis CI
- Packaging/Deployment: Docker, LXC
- Version Control:Git, Github
- Logging: ELK Stack
- Virtualization/Provisioning: Vagrant, Virtualbox
- Cloud resources: DigitalOcean, AWS, Azure, OpenStack

I know I'm missing multiple components here (like security or storage), and I'd gladly take suggestions regarding that as well but I'm mostly concerned with these for the moment.

Some good resources of development [roles](https://mattkopala.com/blog/2012/01/08/building-a-development-infrastructure/) and [tooling](https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin) that I've looked at.

Comment: I believe you should get familiar with current GitLab and its gitlab-runner. It handles most of things you mentioned. You can build there good CI with autmoatic deployment, it works perfectly with dockers, also it has its own system for reviews, merge requests, sprints(milestones), task labeling and staging, reports and much more. All my commercial projects are on it and since so I do not need Travis, Jenkins, Github etc. Even you can host static files using Gitlab Pages. All of it is for free atm, you can also host it on your own mashines, or combine official gitlab with private ci runners.

Comment: Also I connect it with slack group of developers and who should get noticed about builds, fails, merger requests, discussions etc can be informed by mail or smartphone app.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to tell you this, but this question is completely wrong from the foundation of the question.

First of, **there's no silver bullet architecture**, an architecture defines the skeleton of a software system to fulfill a set of business needs. There can be no architecture without business needs.

You need to consider that, generally speaking, **a system architecture tries to balance mainly two concepts, flexibility vs complexity**. The more flexible something is, the more complexity is needed to handle it. There're very few occasions where the simplest solution is also the most flexible one.

The trick of a good architecture comes from identifying WHERE and WHY the flexibility is preferred over simplicity and WHERE and WHY simplicity is preferred over flexibility... and that is always business related. Your tooling, your programming language, your ALM, your devops tools, your database... that all depends on your business.

Now... with all of the above said, do you want simplicity or flexibility? Let's look at your statement:

> I want to have a setup for a solo development environment ... if I were to start a company, what is the best foundation...

You're looking at this the wrong way. You're dreaming too much... it will never work, never, ever... I'm sorry.

**You have a team of one and you don't even have a product to sell**. Stop thinking about that time when you'll have a 10.000 users per second and you're floating on money... you're not there, when you get there you can start thinking about complex architectures... Do you think Zuckerberg started with a multinode, bigdata, highly scalable architecture based on the latest tools and practices for Facebook? He didn't. He started with what he knew and focused on CREATING a product for the intended target: a single university... he knew he needed to support ONE university, a couple hundred users... he wasn't architecting for 500 million users, and I can tell you that first version of facebook didn't look anything like the current one... and there you have it still.

You need to do the same, stop focusing on flexibility, start focusing on simplicity... **you need to have a product soon, and first... not only to have something to sell, but also to learn about what you actually need. You will not get it right the first time... you need to iterate**

If you start planning for dynamic growth, scalability, devops, automatic deployments, etc... the complexity of thinking about that will eat up your time and you'll never even get your product started, it will die before it even has a chance to start. Complex architectures are for complex teams and complex products... well stablished products that actually NEED the flexibility, that actually NEED the scalability. Nothing is free. Way before you have 10.000 clients and your system is overloading with pressure, you will have enough money to hire people to handle all that, to establish good devops practices, to worry about scaling the system...

**Do not architect your system for the distant future, architect your system for today's requirement with a view on next year requirements and estimations.**

Answer (score 1):

In general, I always think of it as 3 parts:

1. Source control.
2. Build (CI).
3. Deploy (CD).

Very important part is, you need to pick a combination that works **together** well. There are many tools for each part which shine in isolation, but without connecting all these together, you won't get much benefit for your CI/CD process. Hence, there are minimum expectations these need to meet.

Source control:

1. Hold the source and its versions.
2. Expose capability **for Build tools** to identify that a new check-in has happened. This does not have to be a push style event, it can be that the build tool simply compares last known version to the current version, every now and then.
3. Expose capability **for Build tools** to retrieve code.

Build:

1. Able to connect **to Source control system**, identify a new check-in, and retrieve code.
2. Build code.
3. Run unit-tests.
4. Expose build results **for Deploy tools**.
5. Nice to have - ability to execute custom scripts and custom build steps.

Deploy:

1. Able to connect **to Build tools** and retrieve all successful build outputs for selection.
2. Able to deploy build output as the target application type (service, web, etc) to the target machines.
3. Nice to have - ability to execute custom scripts and custom build steps.
4. Nice to have - support several environments for applications, such as dev, integration, pre-prod, prod.

---

### What I have tried and works

1. Source control - either TFS or GitHub enterprise.
2. Build - TeamCity.
3. Deploy - Octopus.

There are many alternatives to these, and it seems you have found numerous of those already. Only thing is, I would not choose more than 3 to accomplish just 3 basic goals that you need to focus on (don't over-engineer). What exact tools to pick - does not really matter, as long as you know what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

A solid fundation start, in my opinion is to base your architecture on opensource software supported by an existing community.

The methodology will be (in my opinion):

Using the same API endpoint for both staff, customer and public (with proper user permission) permit as all services needs the same architecture, to help you to minimize the cost of maintain and update code in long term view, and also will definitly increase the easy continuous integration.

> Integration in this API model conception, consist of adding some api end
>   point, and relative web page template who use this api end point to show/get the
>   content/result you want to integrate

You may start with an 'elastic' instance running [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (as API microframework) + [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) (as NoSQL database), hosted in any cloud data-center is a good start for back office infra.

Another 'elastic' instance for ressource (html, js, css, img, file etc...)

When load increase, you may setup [(geo)replication with mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) in order to increase redundancy and data availability.
Aand to increase the website serving speed you may setup a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) service or use existing a commercial one (cloudflare...) if the charge and the (internationnal) load require this or in order to avoid any DDoS attack on your public infrastructure.

If you need to treat data with a very low latency (or to decrease latency):
- on database side : use [REDIS](https://redis.io/) (in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker) and [RabitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) 
- if you would also very low latency beetween your infrastructure and customer side : use [Websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) ([autobahn](http://crossbar.io/autobahn/) as  Web Application Messaging Protocol (WAMP) ) to push and get data from website user.

And also Github (or 'github'-like) for hosting API source code, and also backoffice source code version.

Finaly you need to dev some specific script to deploy from last stable github branch directly to the 'elastic instance' for both API and ressource

Hope it will help you. Regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer for this. Instead, I am providing a loose and unscientific framework that can hopefully help answer this question. Although I'm only writing this down now, it is a variation on how I usually think these things through. If anyone has anything to add, I'm open. Maybe I'm missing an important part.

Sometimes answers may contradict each other. In this case, I can't tell you which to go with, because the fact is that developing is always about a series of tradeoffs. You cannot have a perfect program, that is developed quickly and efficiently, that is bug free and complex. The missing ingredient that makes these combinations impossible is time. If you try to achieve everything, you will achieve nothing.

So, here goes:

### 1. What am I familiar with?

If you are building a new site, unless you are going out with the express interest of learning a new language or stack, or unless the other questions have answers that contradict this one, stick with what you know.

### 2. What are others familiar with?

If you plan on making your program open source, or involving a team, browse a coding website, like, say, StackOverflow, and see how [active specific tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) are. Want to create your own custom program written entirely in Perl? That's probably not going to get you too many fans and will limit the pool from which you can draw in 2016.

### 3. Are my solutions widely used and do they conform to standards?

Ultimately, if, for example, you use Travis CI for continuous integration and [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) for continuous deployment, you'll probably be OK, because both are widely used. If, in the future, you want to change your deployment system, or change your integration system, you will probably find a host of solutions out there. Both of these programs have developer support behind them, which means you can stay flexible. Similarly, if you are going to go the framework route, find a framework that is widely used and has a large developer community.

### 4. How modular are my processes?

Using the same Travis CI/Capistrano example... There are a number of options, such as a custom deployment, that are difficult to extend and hard to understand. Even if you use solutions from the same provider, it may be helpful to consider how mixable and matchable these pieces are. All things being equal, the more modular your processes are, the better.

### 5. Is this necessary right now?

If you're following #4 and considering #1, it is worth asking yourself if what you're looking at is vitally necessary right now. In a modular setup, you should be able to add a step as necessary without much to slow you down. It is a lot easier to add necessary complexity than to deal with unnecessary complexity.

### 6. What is your deadline?

This might be the most important question. If you need to build something by the end of the year and it's a hard deadline for a client, say, you're probably going to highlight #1 over #2. If your deadline is a little further out or is softer, maybe #2 becomes more important.

---

Now, your specific questions, with this framework applied, as examples. Please note that I am putting MY judgement into this, so hopefully you take this as an exercise rather than my decided opinion.

> Configuration Management: Puppet, Ansible

Both have good support. I would go with what I knew or what I was more comfortable with or found simpler. You can always switch these around in the future if you have more sysadmins and someone has a preference.

> CI: Jenkins, Travis CI

Again, both have good support. One can be replaced with another in the future without affecting other parts of your process workflow, so just go with one and stick with it.

> Packaging/Deployment: Docker, LXC

I would ask myself if I needed this as part of my workflow initially. Ultimately, this ties into Virtualization/Provisioning. Do you really need a Dockerized system if you're running everything off of a committed virtual host? For me, I might think this adds unecessary complexity off the bat. If, however, I were intimately familiar with Docker, I might decide that was preferable to running my deployment off of a Virtual Host.

> Version Control:Git, Github

Personally, I think Git is the greatest. Github is actually just a GUI wrapper for Git, but it's one that's well done and that people are very familiar with. You cannot run a repository on Github without having a git repository. If I am already familiar with GitHub, I'd be inclined to use it because it checks off all the boxes.

> Logging: ELK Stack

To be honest, I have not used or looked at ELK stack, but I have used Splunk. The questions here apply. If you check off enough boxes, go for it and use ELK. I would highlight the "Is this necessary right now?" question though, as you might want to prioritize other elements. Of course, if you don't incorporate a logger you may kick yourself for losing valuable data on day 1. I can't answer it for you, but you can answer it for yourself.

> Virtualization/Provisioning: Vagrant, Virtualbox

See the point on Docker. The big question is... Do you need both? And are you using them [in sync with each other](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/docker.html)? Your call, and all a matter of your needs right now.

> Cloud resources: DigitalOcean, AWS, Azure, OpenStack

Here's where it can be especially important to answer the 6 questions above. What, amongst these, are you more familiar with and what are others more familiar with? All of these are going to be good options. I've used DigitalOcean, AWS and Azure, and I can tell you that they all have their selling propositions.

Hypothetically, if you have several terabytes or more of data in the future, and can't have any downtime, moving servers is a non-trivial task. Now,  if you're lucky enough to get to that point, you may end up pulling a Dropbox and [creating your own cloud](https://www.wired.com/2016/03/epic-story-dropboxs-exodus-amazon-cloud-empire/). The major point is, you have no idea what's coming in the future. So, focus on the present. Ultimately, pick the one you are most comfortable with, that others probably are most comfortable with, and go with it. Also, see what sort of companies use each system. If this question is holding you back, though, best to just flip a coin. You can always switch in the future.

### Summary

There is never going to be a single right answer. What is right at year-end of 2016 may be very wrong by year-end of 2017. What is right for your early-stage company may prove to be wrong for your mid- or late-stage company. Finding solutions which allow you to find the balance of getting off the ground quickly and easily switching solutions down the road will make your business and software more flexible. There are countless case studies of businesses changing their business logic and automated workflows to suit changing conditions.

Ultimately, the quickest way to be wrong with your selection is to reject the inevitable truth that your needs will change, and your selections should change with them.